# Initializing a database client in a trait

Tags: scala, initialization, singleton, traits

I have a trait DbClientUtil that is as follows:

```
trait DbClientUtil{
   lazy val dbClient = //Initializing client here
}
```

I have a Dbhelper object that extends the DbClientUtil trait as follows:

```
object DbHelper extends DbClientUtil{
   def sendDbPayload(dbModel:DbModel):Unit = {
        dbClient.sendData(dbModel)
   }
}
```

In the above given example `sendData` is a method on `dbClient`.

Now I want to iterate through a collection, convert the elements to a model, send it to the db and then shutdown the client.

So, I write out this strategy in the following object

```
object Runner extends DbClientUtil{
   import DbHelper._
   List(DbModel("model1"),DbModel("model2"),DbModel("model3")).foreach{
      model => sendDbPayload(model)
   }
   dbClient.shutdown
}
```

I have two objects that extend the same trait. `DBHelper` and `Runner` extend the same trait `DbClientUtil`. The `DbClientUtil` initializes the `dbClient`. The initialized `dbClient` is being used by both the  `DbHelper` and the `Runner`. My question is, am I initializing `dbClient` twice? My next question would be if I am initializing it twice, what would be a better way to rewrite this to prevent any redundant initializations?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually yes. DbClientUtil initializes twice: first by DbHelper and then by Runner. If this is a problem, there are a lot of ways to solve this:

1) make `DbClientUtil` stateless and rewrite it as `def dbClient`. It is actually a good solution, because your state should be stored in a database without any depends on how many clients you have instantiated

2) create singleton. Just one. Not two:

```
object DbClientUtil extends DbClientUtil

object DbHelper extends DbClientUtil{
  def sendDbPayload(dbModel:DbModel):Unit = {
    DbClientUtil.sendData(dbModel)
  }
}

object Runner {
       List(DbModel("model1"),DbModel("model2"),DbModel("model3")).foreach{
     model => DbHelper.sendDbPayload(model)
  }
  DbHelper.shutdown //Use just one client, not two
}
```

But actually I don't like this. Strict dependencies gives you more coupling

3) Use dependency injection. I guess this is the one of best solution for large projects. For example, you can use Google Guice:

```
trait DbClientService {
   def sendData(data: Any): Unit //No implementation
}

class DbClientServiceImpl extends DbClientService
   def sendData(data: Any): Unit {
      //write you implementation code
   }
}
```

Bind it:
https://github.com/codingwell/scala-guice/

```
class ServiceModule extends AbstractModule {
  protected def configure() {
    bind[DbClientService].to[DbClientServiceImpl].in[Singleton]
  }
}
```

And then inject it:

```
class DbHelper @Inject()(dbClient:DbClientService) extends DbClientUtil{
  def sendDbPayload(dbModel:DbModel):Unit = {
    dbClient.sendData(dbModel)
  }
}

class Runner @Inject()(dbClient:DbClientService) extends DbClientUtil{

  List(DbModel("model1"),DbModel("model2"),DbModel("model3")).foreach{
     model => dbClient.sendDbPayload(model)
  }
  dbClient.shutdown 
  //still, don't know if it is good solution 
  //to control client state from outer scope
  //better make this logic private
}
```